# SQL future dates in request

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to execute an SQL request to get all future events.

So far, it looks like this :

```
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AOFVHFlyBundle:Flight a WHERE precisedate >= NOW()";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
```

But I get the following error:

```
line 0, col 59: Error: Expected known function, got 'NOW'
```

How can i get all my future flights ?

Comment: try using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ` instead of `NOW()`

Comment: Hi @Pierre Olivier Tran if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DQL Function you are looking for is the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`. As described in the [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Try using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP no parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, you can create your own DQL function. Just an another option.

For full example: [How to create and use custom built doctrine DQL function in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/cgo2/how-to-create-and-use-custom-built-doctrine-dql-function-in-symfony)

```
# sport/src/Football/FrontendBundle/DQL/NowTs.php
namespace Football\FrontendBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class NowTs extends FunctionNode
{
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'NOW()';
    }
}
```

In your query:

```
->where('..... < NOW() ....')
```